# Update component in react with socketio when component mount and unmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I am working in a app where I am reciving messages throw socketio. I have created a component in a way that every time I recive a message from socketio I am rendering a card with that message. That is working, the issue is that if I unmount the component, once I mount it again, I am able to see the components from before and the new ones, but I am unable to keep the ones that were arraving while the component was unmount. What would be the right approach for achive that?

I guess I need to take out socket connection from the component since I want to keep all the messages recived during the session

```
export default function MessagePage() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("message", (messageSocket) => {
      let mess = JSON.parse(messageSocket);
      setMessage(mess);
    });
  }, [])

  return <Message message={message} />
}
```

```
let messageCollection = [];

export default function Message({ message }) {
  const [messageState, setMessageState] = useState([]);

  messageCollection.unshift(message);
  useEffect(() => {
    setMessageState(messageCollection);
  }, [message])

  return (
    <>
      {messageState.map(mes => (
          <Message
            ...
          />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

I guess I would need to do something like save the messages in an array while the user is in a different page, but I think I would still have the problem of render those that have been saved and those that are arriving every few seconds from socketio.

Comment: I think saving the messages in an array would work, but if the user refreshes the page those messages would again be gone. So the best way is to use a backend server and save the messages in the database.

Comment: That would help you rendering all the old messages in thrown by socket, also the new messages can be shown in the way you are doing right now

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea, an user can see the messages that were created during the session. Other wise, I give option for requesting to server the data. So I think the option of saving them in an array in client side is the one, but still I am not sure how to manage for saving all of them with component mount or not and then show everything that arrived once I move to that page, so old messages, messages that arrived while component was unmount and the new that are arriving.